# Can I move a std::unique_ptr<T> into a std::vector<T>?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Say I have a vector of some generic T objects:

```
std::vector<T> vector_of_ts = {...};
```

That vector is basically a heap-allocated array of T objects, under the hood. Now, say I have the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> t = std::make_unique<T>(...);
```

Again, this is a heap-allocated T object under the hood. Is it possible to push back that object to the vector *by moving it*, without making temporary/extra copies? Something like:

```
vector_of_ts.move(*t)
```

Comment: No, the vector is not an array of pointers, it's a contiguous array. You can use the move constructor of an object to move it into the vector but it'll be a new object

Comment: You might misunderstand what it means to "[move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)" an object. Whether or not an object is heap-allocated has no bearing on whether or not it can be moved. Also, moving an object usually involves copying *some* data, just not always all the data.

Comment: Be careful with object slicing when moving your `unique_ptr<T>` into a `vector<T>`. If `unique_ptr<T>` is a polymorphic base (which might be the reason it's a pointer in the first place), you slice your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector_of_ts.emplace_back(std::move(*t))` will let you move the T from the unique_ptr into the vector: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/1qdzznz7h)

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct T
{
    // Can't be copied
    T() = default;
    T(const T&) = delete;
    T(T&&) = default;
    T &operator=(const T&) = delete;
    T &operator=(T&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T> vector_of_ts;
    std::unique_ptr<T> t = std::make_unique<T>();

    // error: use of deleted function T::T(const T&)
    vector_of_ts.emplace_back(*t);

    // Success
    vector_of_ts.emplace_back(std::move(*t));
}
```

Note that after the move, `t` points to the moved-from `T` object. The state of this object depends on what the move constructor does (std containers for example are left in a "valid but unspecified" state, meaning you shouldn't do anything with them except destroy them or reassign to them).

Answer (score 2):

You can move-construct a *new* `T` object in the `std::vector` in the same way you move-construct any object, i.e. `vector_of_ts.push_back(std::move(*t))`, but you can't somehow move *the same* `T` object into the vector.

---

A `std::vector<T>` is a *contiguous* container.  That is, under the hood it's a pointer to one big dynamically-allocated chunk of memory in which some number of `T` objects reside.

A `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a pointer to a *single* dynamically-allocated `T` object.

You can't "add" the `T` object pointed to by the `std::uniqeu_ptr` to the `std::vector` because it isn't a part of the contiguous memory block managed by the `std::vector`.